# My object is not moving smoothly, but in increments of one unit

Tags: modeling, interface

What is preventing my objects from moving smoothly? Instead of moving slowly and precisely, the object moves by one unit

[image]

[image].

Comment: are you talking about an animation or just moving objects in the scene? You must have enabled the Snap option (magnet icon button) / Increment (grid) mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> while in object mode to Exit [**Transform Snapping**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181119110240/https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snap)

For 2.79

[image]
<sub>(source: [blender.org](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/_images/editors_3dview_object_editing_transform_control_snap_header-magnet-icon.png))</sub>

For 2.8

[image]

Comment: maybe explain why it will fix the problem  ;)